# How to overcome strange NIntegrate behaviour

Tags: functions, numerical-integration

Direct calculation of a simple converging integral gives the correct result:

```
NIntegrate[1/(1 - I x) Exp[-I x], {x, -∞, ∞}]

(* 2.31145 - 1.11022*10^-16 I *)
```

We can check it:

```
2. π/E

(* 2.31145 *)
```

However if I calculate the same integral using a function it fails:

```
i[y_?NumericQ] = 1/(1 - I y) Exp[-I y];
NIntegrate[i[x], {x, -∞, ∞}]

(* NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9
recursive bisections in x near {x} = {6.3887*10^56}. NIntegrate obtained
3.96859 -328.962 I and 245.98686501304076` for the integral and error estimates.

3.96859 - 328.962 I *)
```

I have tried various methods and options, but was unable to get the correct result.

What is the problem, and how to solve it in the general case?

*Update*: in real life i[y] represents a black box, which can be evaluated only numerically. Here is a plot of my "real" function for numerical integration:
[image]

It has the same asymptotic behavior as the simple function in my oversimplified example.

Comment: The second function cannot be symbolically analyzed by `NIntegrate[]`, so it uses its default algorithm, which is not too good for oscillatory integrals like yours.

Comment: And what method should I use? I have already tried all of them...

Comment: In at least this simple case, you could try deforming the contour, but what might work for this toy problem might not work for your actual one.

Comment: Do you mean using i[x + 0.001 I] instead of i[x] ? Unfortunately it does not help...

Comment: Wow, that's... a lot of wiggles. I'm sure a good contour choice can at least ease the numerics. Let me think about it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yes, my actual black box looks very similar to the example. It also contains oscillating exponent, but the prefactor depends on y in much more complicated way.
>
> -- [OP's comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/153896/how-to-overcome-strange-nintegrate-behaviour#comment411088_153905)

Taking the comment literally, assuming the exponential factor is known, and assuming the product of the exponential and prefactor is computed numerically, one can use the following approach:

Let `i[y]` be the numerical integrand.  Then divide and multiply by the exponential factor as follows:

```
i[y_?NumericQ] = 1/(1 - I y) Exp[-I y];  (* OP's numerical integrand *)
i2[y_?NumericQ] := i[y] / Exp[-I y];     (* OP's divided by exponential *)
NIntegrate[i2[x] Exp[-I x], {x, -∞, ∞}]  (* multiply back by exponential *)
(*  2.31145 + 0. I  *)
```

The symbolic product `i2[x] Exp[-I x]` can be analyzed symbolically (using the `"LevinRule"`).  The `?NumericQ` on `i2` prevents the exponential factors from canceling symbolically.

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
i[y_] := 1/(1 - I y) Exp[-I y];
NIntegrate[i[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]

(*  2.31  *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: Thank you! Definitely it works, because it is just equivalent to my first example. However, I want to be able to work with numerical function, because in my initial code i[y] is intended to represent some numerical sum. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: @Dmitry What do you mean by "numerical function"? Why do not you post an example of the function you have in mind?

Comment: @Alexei, he used `i[y_?NumericQ] = 1/(1 - I y) Exp[-I y];` as a simple example of a black box (note the `_?NumericQ` pattern) that `NIntegrate[]` won't be able to analyze. Basically, pretend you can't actually see the definition, and you can only evaluate the integrand at numerical values.

Comment: @ J. M. That means, he should simply refuse of using this definition. Or I do not understand something?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch The one in the OP might be a minimal working example. For more complex functions that can only be evaluated numerically, the problem would persist.

Comment: Indeed originally I had much more complicated function i[y], which is given by infinite sum with the parameter y. This sum in general case can be evaluated only numerically. Then I want to take some rather complicated integral with this function. I have found, that I can not calculate it despite it is definitely converging. Therefore I oversimplified my problem in order to give a minimal working example. If you help me to solve this one, I am pretty sure, that it will work in my original problem.

Comment: @Dmitry, is your actual black box also oscillatory? You don't need to post the entire infinite sum; I just want to have an idea of what makes your function wiggly (e.g. Fourier series)

Comment: @J.M. Yes, my actual black box looks very similar to the example. It also contains oscillating exponent, but the prefactor depends on y in much more complicated way. Nevertheless it has the same asymptote for large y.

Comment: @Dmitry, if you'll indulge me one more time, can you at least post a plot of the integrand (over, say, $[-10,10]$ or whatever interval you believe to be most illustrative) to help with figuring out what tricks might work best? (If you do, please edit your question to include it.)

Comment: @J.M. I have updated my question. Does it help?